# Android - size of the screen that is currently displayed

Tags: android, opengl-es-1.1

I am a developer in Korea.

I avail weak point very English.

Try to draw the ocean map using OpenGL ES.

Therefore, it is us with a direct manipulation of movement when you touch the screen, zoom in / zoom out function.

To get the movement value to know the difference between the width height of the screen according to the zoom state of each is likely to be.

Is there a way to check the internal coordinates of the lower right and the most coordinate of the top left of the screen to be projected in the current Android?

We can not speak English, you can complement the description of the picture.

[image]

Please help me.

Are unable to work.

Comment: maybe have a look at this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions

Comment: Thank's for tour answer dunn~! This page was really helpful. However, the same height, width values ​​only is also shown when you try to view the log for each of the state of the zoom level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this will help you:

```
getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer~! However, I do not know. Renderer class for a function which can be used to undergo inherit the activity class